# 自～／他～ペア：逆の形 -- Transitive/Intransitive pairs: opposite forms

Tags: verbs, transitivity, morphology

I've noticed (through much frustration) that many 自～／他～ pairs have "opposite" forms; particularly with the ~u and ~eru types.  For example, 焼く・焼ける are opposite from 開く・開ける.

> 焼く　（他）　－　パン**を**焼く ("Bake bread")
> 焼ける　（自）－　パン**が**ちょうどよく焼けた ("The bread was baked just right")
>
> 開く　（自）　－　ドア**が**ひとりでに開いた！怖いでしょう！ ("The door opened by itself!  Isn't that creepy?")
> 開ける　（他）－　彼女のためにドア**を**開けてあげる ("I open doors for my girlfriend")

Is there any logical reason that some pairs like these have "opposite" forms???  Or is it just to piss off the people trying to learn them??

Comment: A web search shows that there is a [paper](http://nihon5ch.net/contents/ch5/daigakuin/gengo-2008-3-part1.pdf) (in Japanese) about this very topic.

Comment: すごいですね。読んでみます。恐縮です！

Comment: Hahaha!  今読みつつ、挙げられている例も同じ！偶然だろっ！

Comment: Wow, I think I'd need to read that about 20 more times to fully comprehend it.  In short:  it's complicated.

Comment: “In short: it's complicated.”  Haha, I guessed so. :)

Comment: +1 Because your second question rocks and I'm sure every student of Japanese asks the same question at some point.

Comment: @istrasci: Google tells me that 恐縮です = ...is Kyoshuku. Is this correct? I have a feeling Google is wrong and you meant something else. But I wanted to make sure. Either way, I have no idea what 恐縮です means :)

Comment: @dotnetN00b: Yes, that's correct.  `恐縮` is a polite way of saying "thank you".  Like, "much obliged".  And yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/ti_list.html Has a good list of them, in case you wanted to see them at a glance.

Nothing I could find gave a good reason for it.  Probably the language just evolved organically, as they tend to do.

Of course, linguists will try to explain anything, so I'm not surprised that Japanese paper is so hard to digest.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it and just learn the words in context.

Answer (score 1):

Re: organic evolution, I note that Shogakukan's comprehensive JA-JA *Kokugo Dai Jiten Dictionary* lists most (maybe all?) of these verbs as having originally been both transitive and intransitive.  I suspect the different conjugations (*ichidan* vs. *nidan*) evolved as a way of being more specific.

By way of comparison, there are verbs in English that are both transitive or intransitive depending on context: consider *begin* or *hang* or *stop*.  English and other Germanic languages also have vaguely similar pairs that differ by the core vowel, which changes depending on whether it's transitive or intransitive: consider *lie*, *lay* or *sit*, *set*.  English grammar has certain requirements of subject-object word order and the explicit presence of subject and object that clarify the situation even for the verbs that don't have a vowel change to indicate transitivity (*the test **began***, *I **began** the test*, etc.), whereas Japanese does not, making transitivity potentially very ambiguous without some other means of specifying a difference in sense.  The *ichidan* to *nidan* shift may have evolved as such a way of being specific, perhaps in a way similar to the vowel shift in certain verb pairs in Germanic languages.

Given the scattershot nature of the original verbs (where two-mora verb forms could be either transitive or intransitive, depending on the individual verbs themselves, such as transitive 焼{や}く vs. intransitive 開{あ}く as in your example pair), and given also the presence of verbs like つく that still exhibit ambiguity (modern つく could still be either transitive or intransitive, as in 突く *to poke something, to stab something* vs. 着く *to arrive*), learning whether *-u* or *-eru* is transitive or intransitive appears to be one of those areas of the language where there isn't any systemic set of rules, and instead you'll just have to learn the verbs over time.