# Difference between 折る and 折れる

Tags: verbs, jlpt, transitivity

What's the difference between `折【お】る` and `折【お】れる`? According to my dictionary, they both mean `to break` or `to fold`. When would you use one over the other? These verbs are on the [JLPT N4 vocabulary list](http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/jlpt4/vocab).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an example of a [自他]{じ・た} pair.  These pairs are an important concept to learn in Japanese because there are a *ton* of them!  [[Here]{LLLL}](http://www.mlcjapanese.co.jp/Download/ViVt.pdf) [[are]{LLL}](http://nihongo.monash.edu/ti_list.html) [[several]{LLLLLLL}](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/in-transitive) [[resources]{LLLLLLLLL}](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar/Transitivity) with lots of examples and good explanations.

---

折る is a [他動詞]{た・どう・し} which is a transitive verb.  This means an external agent/influence performs the action in question.  You can remember this because 他 is also read as 「ほか」, meaning "(an)other"; so something *other* than the object itself performs the action on the object.  With transitive verbs, you'll have **を** to show that the external agent performs the action **on** something.  In the case of 折る you might have something like

> - 花子は左腕の骨**を**折った　→　Hanako broke (the bone of) her left arm
> - 僕は枝**を**踏んで折った　→　I stepped on the branch and broke it
> - 手紙**を**折る　→　Fold a letter

---

折れる is a [自動詞]{じ・どう・し} which is an intransitive verb.  This means the action happens to the thing/object itself, and the object is the focus.  You can remember this by remembering 自 means "itself", like 自分.  With intransitive verbs, since the focus is the thing itself, you'll have **は** or **が** to show this focus.  In case of 折れる:

> - 枝**が**折れた　→　The branch (itself) broke
> - 本が落ちて、何枚ものページ**が**折れた　→　The book fell, and several pages were bent/"folded".

---

If you want some extra confusion after you learn the basics, check out

- [自～／他～ペア：逆の形 — Transitive/Intransitive pairs: opposite forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1306/78)
- [Passive-transitive-verb vs. Intransitive-verb （他動詞の受け身 vs. 自動詞)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/329/78)
- [How do 自他 triplets of related verbs work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12837/78)

Answer (score 6):

折る is a transitive verb and 折れる is intransitive. Keep in mind 折れる could also mean the conjugated potential form of 折る.

Answer (score 2):

As other users told, 折る is a transitive verb that requires an objective such as 折り紙を折る　－　do an origami. 折れる is an intransitive verb, like 箸が折れる　chopsticks snap. It requires a subjective.

折る、折れる aren't necessarily referring to physical objects like a branch, tree, bones, and a window glass. It can be used for abstract objects, for examples:

> 骨を折る　- make an serious effort, take care of (someone else)
>
> 話を折る - interrupt others' story, stop other's talking.

腰を折る - block / check someone's attempt

> 心が折れる - discouraged, down-hearted