# Existence of Transitive/intransitive pairs

Tags: transitivity

I searched for the answer for this specific question of mine, but couldn't find it. So I'm sorry If I duplicated some thread.

I was reading some stuff here about 自動詞 and 他動詞 and start wondering if all verbs in japanese come in transitive/intransitive pairs like 付く/付ける.

Is this true?

Comment: Related:  [自～／他～ペア：逆の形 — Transitive/Intransitive pairs: opposite forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1306/78), [How do 自他 triplets of related verbs work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12837/78).

Answer (score 6):

Not all verbs come in transitive/intransitive pairs.

Quite a few intransitive verbs have no transitive counterpart. To name a few...

> ある、[行]{い}く、[来]{く}る、[歩]{ある}く、[走]{はし}る、[座]{すわ}る、かみつく、そびえる、[響]{ひび}く etc...

<sub>行かせる, 来させる, 歩かせる etc. are causative forms (使役形), consisting of conjugated form 「行か」 + auxiliary 「せる」, conjugated form 「[来]{こ}」 + auxiliary 「させる」, etc.</sub>

... and quite a few transitive verbs have no intransitive copunterpart. To name a few...

> [読]{よ}む、[話]{はな}す、[置]{お}く、[食]{た}べる、[殺]{ころ}す、[調]{しら}べる、[投]{な}げる、[蹴]{け}る、[打]{う}つ、もらう etc...

And, there're a few cases where the transitive verb and intransitive verb share the same form, such as in:

> [開]{ひら}く -- ドアが[開]{ひら}く(intransitive) / ドアを[開]{ひら}く(transitive)
>   [閉]{と}じる -- まぶたが[閉]{と}じる(intransitive) / まぶたを[閉]{と}じる(transitive)

Answer (score 2):

> I was reading some stuff here about 自動詞 and 他動詞 and start wondering if all verbs in japanese come in transitive/intransitive pairs like 付く/付ける.
>   Is this true?

No.

Many Japanese verbs have intransitive and corresponding transitive verbs as written in the article [here](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Pulin/20150214/1423890973), but there are transitive verbs that do not have intransitive verbs as written in the last part of the article [here](https://www.alc.co.jp/jpn/article/faq/03/41.html) as follows.

> また、すべての動作動詞が自他の対応をもつわけではなく、自動詞をもたない動詞も少なからず見られます。
>
> 次郎が机を叩く。
>   　　花子が荷物をもつ。
>
> このように、対応する自動詞をもたない動詞には、行為の対象の状態変化に無関心であるという、共通した特徴が観察されます。

According to the explanation, "Common features are observed in the transitive verbs without corresponding intransitive verbs, which are indifferent to the state change of the object of action."

Answer (score 0):

They don't always come in pairs or obey the patterns, you can learn/study about transitive intransitive verbs with
[Japanese Verbs Transitive Intransitive - TaJi - 他自](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.yamayama.taji&hl=en)

*I am the developer of the app.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to provide some relevant information here? Answers should be as self-contained as possible. Otherwise, your answer may be considered  “link only” and possibly deleted.