# Is there a way to conjucate transitive verbs to intransitive verbs ? or a pattern to use?

Tags: verbs, conjugations, transitivity

In the last lesson I had in my Japanese course, we learned about transitive verbs & intransitive verbs.

In the Genki II book, there's no explanation as to how a verb is transformed from transitive to intransitive or vice versa.

I searched online and on YouTube for possible explanation as to how we conjugate between the pair and I found no such thing.

Some patterns I can find:

- A lot of intransitive verbs always covert from a godan verb to an ichidan verb.
- And the letter before the る is set to the ~e letters.
- Ichidan verbs usually remove the る and covert to a godan verb for the intransitive counterpart (but not always, e.g. 閉める→閉まる, the る stays but the verb still converted to a godan verb)

So I was wondering if there was a rule of thumb for converting between the two pairs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Patterns (and exceptions) for 自動詞 - 他動詞 pairs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56454)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [とまる / とめる and such pairs of verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14861/%e3%81%a8%e3%81%be%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%a8%e3%82%81%e3%82%8b-and-such-pairs-of-verbs) There are some useful patterns, but there is no "rule" here. You have to remember both of them separately (*rise* vs *raise* is a good example in English).