How does 化かす meaning to deceive; bewitch or delude work, when it's seemingly the す form of 化ける?
Is it similar to the modern transitive form/す form of verbs with ambiguous transitivity in their archaic form where す just acts as a transitivity agent for the stem of the word and therefore the base meaning (Although I would not quite know how such a thing would allow the transitive version of the verb to basically mean the same thing as the intransitive verb except that it acts on an object and focuses on a specific aspect of 化)? When I looked it up, it also has the causative of 化ける meaning alongside of it. Also, I wonder if this is just a redundant question related to the arbitrariness of things like 受ける with the meaning of "to be well received" being able to be intransitive (Actually, I think this meaning may be backformed from 受け/ウケ; Actually, it seems that it is an abbreviation of a transitive phrase, so, not arbitrary).

I'm not sure what you're asking. Essentially, is this what you're asking?: "When you 氷を溶かす, the result is 氷が溶ける. When you アイディアを活かす, the result is アイディアが活きる. However, when a fox 人間を化かす, the result is not 人間が化ける. Why?" Or are you just asking why 化かす gained the meaning of "to deceive"?

I know that it doesn't mean 人間を化けさせる, I was just stating that it also had  that meaning. I am inquiring about how it got the "deceive" meaning (I know shapeshifting implies that from 化ける but I don't know what す is doing here and how it would come or be allowed to mean deceive with it. (Edit: It's midnight and I misread, yes, that is precisely what I'm asking, exactly that, along with the other question.)

Why does only 化かす mean "to deceive"?
The intransitive verb 化ける already strongly implies "to deceive".
In Japanese lore and tales such as 化け猫, 傘お化け, かちかち山 and ごんぎつね, creatures and animals use their shapeshifting (化ける) ability almost exclusively to delude, bewitch, trick, or harm humans. To simply refer to shapeshifting (e.g., of Spider-Man or werewolves) itself, we use 変身する.
Conversely, 化かす is not a generic term for deceiving. The subject of 化かす is almost always an entity like 狐, 狸, 幽霊, and 妖怪 that uses their shapeshifting ability to trick humans. We don't say 詐欺師が老人を化かして金銭を奪う, for example.
Therefore, whether it's 化ける or 化かす, the core meaning is the same: "to use one's shapeshifting ability to delude/bewitch/trick humans".
Why does 化かす not mean 化けさせる?
This is indeed an interesting observation. As I mentioned in the comment section, 化ける/化かす does not seem to follow the ordinary rule of intransitive/transitive verb pairs. I don't have a clear answer, but since not all transitive verbs have an intransitive counterpart (ほったらかす came to mind) in the first place, I guess 化かす developed rather independently, not as a genuine transitive counterpart of 化ける. Transitive verbs like 負かす ("to make someone lose") or 溶かす ("to make something melt") are obviously useful, but we seldom need a lexicalized transitive verb that means "to make someone shapeshift".

I think the verb pair 騙る and 騙す are quite similar to 化ける and 化かす, except that だまる (yes, an actual verb linked to 黙る) doesn't make a skip from a general meaning (shapeshift and delude) to just a specific aspect (trick), however because the shapeshift meaning would be entirely irrelevant in a transitive context! Please read this comment, now I'll approve this answer. This definitely needs further investigation, and I don't want the approval of this post to stop that. I wonder how I'll further investigate this. (It's kind of related to the question where I mistook tviv for causative auxiliary す)

The post I am referring to - https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100828/difference-between-%e3%81%8a-vs-%e3%81%82-in-causative-and-passive-form

@StarPeep shapeshift meaning would be entirely irrelevant in a transitive context: Didn't I say this is incorrect? 化ける and 化かす share the same concept. If you feel they're fundamentally different, that's because you're thinking based only on the dictionary definitions without understanding in which context they are used.
